# bash looking in wrong place for python executable

Tags: python, git, bash

Whenever I try to run a python command using the Git Bash terminal on Windows, it looks in the wrong place:

```
$ python --version
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/python.exe: error while loading shared libraries: 
?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The folder containing the python executable has been added to the PATH variable:

```
$ $PATH
bash: /mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/f/bin:/c/_Programming/Python/Installation/Python36-32/Scripts:/c/_Programming/Python/Installation/Python36-32:/c/_Programming/Ruby/Installation/RailsInstaller/Git/cmd:/c/_Programming/Ruby/Installation/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why the Git Bash terminal is looking for python in a location that's not in the PATH.
Accessing python from the Windows terminal works just fine:

```
C:\Windows\System32>python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

How can I get Git Bash to use the correct location for python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the Git usr/bin directory :/usr/bin has a python executable, which is getting read first before your /c/_Programming/Python/Installation/Python36-32/Scripts, ( I assume that where you have installed your python exec). Try changing the PATH to prefix /c/_Programming/Python/Installation/Python36-32/Scripts

Comment: This was likely the problem - there was a python executable in that directory (though I didn't notice it at first). I think your solution would have worked, but I ended up just uninstalling and reinstalling Git for Windows which fixed everything.

Answer (score 4):

The git bash and Windows console are two completely different command line programs. Git bash is a Linux based terminal (with its own set of libraries) ported to Windows, so in order for git bash to know where a program is, you must do it manually. I mean, you have to also set the PATH variable in git bash. [This article](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pip2/Installation/pythonInstall.html) explains how to do it. In short this is what you need to do:

> 1. Launch the program Git Bash in the usual way that you launch Windows programs. A shortcut for Git Bash was created during installation.
> 2. At the command prompt, paste this command export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27". That will tell Windows where to find Python. (This assumes that you installed it in C:\Python27, as we told you to above.)
> 3. Check to make sure that this worked correctly by entering the command python --version. It should say Python 2.7.8 (or 2.7.something), as shown in the figure below.
> 4. Assuming that worked correctly, you will want to set up git bash so that it always knows where to find python. To do that, enter the following command: echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27"' > .bashrc. That will save the command into a file called .bashrc. .bashrc is executed every time git bash launches, so you won’t have to manually tell the shell where to find python again.
> 5. Check to make sure that worked by typing exit, relaunching git bash, and then typing python --version again.

Comment: This didn't work - as I stated in the question, the folder containing python was already in the git bash PATH variable, but git bash was ignoring that and looking somewhere else.